# Is it possible to use a membrane keyboard chip in another membrane keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I have a membrane keyboard that has stopped working. I would like to fix it using the chip of another older keyboard. Is it possible?

Comment: depends... if they used the same chip then yes. if they use the same interface then maybe

Answer (score 0):

if the membranes are the same pattern (or similar enough) it will work,
else all your keys will be scrambled and maybe some won't work at all.

Comment: You can reprogram the layout in your os though.

Comment: If the keyboard chip can actually read the new matrix, and produces scancodes for all the contacts you can.